# How do I submit a Web page with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, email

I've created a three step order form and I need help with the third step.
1. form is filled out by the business and clicks on "preview order"
2. business views their order and clicks "confirm" (should be on "bizform.php" but I haven't tried it because I have no clue on how to do it.)
3. by clicking "confirm" the "Web page" or data from "bizform.php" is sent to the business and myself.

Questions: Is it possible? If so, can you point me in the right direction? TYVM

My form:

```
    <div class="span4 diff">
    <h3>Business Information</h3>
    <br/>
    <form action="bizform.php" method="post">
    <label for="bizName" class="control-label">
    Business:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="input-large">

    <label for="bizAddress" class="control-label">
    Business Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizAddress" name="bizAddress" class="input-large">

    <label for="bizCity" class="control-label">
    City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizCity" name="bizCity" class="input-large">

    <label for="bizState" class="control-label">
    State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizState" name="bizState" class="input-large">

    <label for="bizZip" class="control-label">
    Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizZip" name="bizZip" class="input-large">

    <label for="fullName" class="control-label">
    Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="input-large">

    <label for="bizEmail" class="control-label">
    E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="bizEmail" name="bizEmail" class="input-large">
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
    <h3>Choose Products</h3>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr class="diffhead">
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Training</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Product One</td>
    <td>$1000.00</td>
    <td>$100.00</td>
    <td>$1100.00</td>
    <td>
    <label class="input" for="productOne"></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" value="0" id="productOne" name="productOne">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product Two</td>
    <td>$1000.00</td>
    <td>$100.00</td>
    <td>$1100.00</td>
    <td>
    <label class="input" for="productTwo"></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" value="0" id="productTwo" name="productTwo">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product Three</td>
    <td>$1000.00</td>
    <td>$100.00</td>
    <td>$1100.00</td>
    <td>
    <label class="input" for="productThree"></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" value="0" id="productThree" name="productThree">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" style="float:left">
    <i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> Cancel Order</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="float:right">Preview Order 
    <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-white"></i></button>
    </form>
    <?php
    include '_inc/footer.html';
    ?>
```

My form processor:

```
        <?php
    include '_inc/header.html';
    ?>
    <?php 

    $bizName = $_POST['bizName'];
    $bizAddress = $_POST['bizAddress'];
    $bizCity = $_POST['bizCity'];
    $bizState = $_POST['bizState'];
    $bizZip = $_POST['bizZip'];
    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
    $bizEmail = $_POST['bizEmail'];

    $productOne = $_POST['productOne'];
    $productTwo = $_POST['productTwo'];
    $productThree = $_POST['productThree'];


    $moneyOff = '';

    $totalPro = $productOne + $productTwo + $productThree;

    define('PRODPRICE', 1100);

    $totalMoney = $productOne * PRODPRICE
    + $productTwo * PRODPRICE
    + $productThree * PRODPRICE;

    if ( $totalMoney == 2200 )
    {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Go Back! You can get a product for free!</div>';
    }

    if ( $totalMoney == 3300 )
    {
    $moneyOff = 1100;
    }
    else
    {
    $moneyOff = 0;
    }


    define('STOCKFEE', 10);
    $stockFee = $productOne * STOCKFEE
    + $productTwo * STOCKFEE
    + $productThree * STOCKFEE;

    ?>
    <h1 align="center">Order Agreement</h1>
    <br/>
    <?php 
    echo '<strong>' .$bizName. '</strong> is purchasing the following products and services from CBE:</p>';
    echo '<div class="well">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="800px">
    <thead>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center">'. $productOne .'</td>
    <td align="center">Product One</td>
    <td align="center">$1,100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center">'. $productTwo .'</td>
    <td align="center">Product Two</td>
    <td align="center">$1,100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center">'. $productThree .'</td>
    <td align="center">Product Three</td>
    <td align="center">$1,100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Sub Total:</td>
    <td align="center">'.number_format($totalMoney,2).'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Discount:</td>
    <td align="center">'.number_format($moneyOff,2).'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Grand Total:</td>
    <td align="center">'.number_format($totalMoney - $moneyOff,2).'</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>';
    echo '<p>Business agrees to pay <strong> '.number_format($totalMoney - $moneyOff,2).' </strong>for these products and services. In addition, Business will pay an additional <strong> '.number_format($stockFee,2).' </strong>to cover stock fee.</p>';
    ?>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
    <div align="left">
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" width="850px">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <?php 
    echo '<strong>' .$bizName. '</strong> <br/>';
    echo $bizAddress.'<br/>';
    echo $bizCity.', ';
    echo $bizState.' ';
    echo $bizZip.'';
    ?>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <strong>CBE</strong><br/>
    Corporate Headquarters<br/>
    555 Main Street<br/>
    PHPLAND, DB 78987-3849<br/>
    888-098-3049
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    include '_inc/footer.html';
    ?>
```

Comment: So you have multiple pages, in which you need to retain the data from each user, until they confirm on bizform.php, correct?

Comment: Yes, and I forgot to mention without using MySQL.

Comment: You could store them using `$_GET` or pass POST variables across the pages. Or, depending on how sensitive the data is, store in sessions or store in cookies.

Comment: Without MySQL, in that case you need to look into sending the data via email.
And between the different pages, you should use sessions.

Comment: You can always store them using $_SESSION or GET or POST and then have them sent to yourself and the business owner via email. Use mail() function

Comment: David, that is a very hacky job?

Comment: I am a noob with PHP...can you explain or show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the the data across multiple forms:

```
<?php
  session_start(); // Initiates the session, and loads the _SESSION variable

  var_dump($_SESSION); // Show the data in the _SESSION variable

  // Load data into the sessions
  $_SESSION['a'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['b'] = 'hello world';

  if (!isset($_SESSION['c'])) $_SESSION['c'] = 0;
  else $_SESSION['c'] += 2;
```

At first, you should see an empty array. Then, refresh and you will see your session data.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php - for reference and further education...

Comment: No worries, IdeaPimp. Just remember, it's actually much easier than it seems!

Comment: Also, do you have any recommendations on how to clean it up? Or make it less of a hack job? Like I said, I am a noob but would like to write cleaner code moving forward.

Comment: IdeaPimp, when I said 'hack job', I was referring to those suggesting you insert the values into the new page, rather than using a session. When you are new to PHP, it will be a hack job in general, however the more you practice, the more you learn.

Comment: IdeaPimp, have a look at these.
http://pastebin.com/Yj1MfCam
http://pastebin.com/Q69rsB8V

They should show you how to implement the sessions enough.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, Shane. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form to bizform.php, store you post variables in hidden input fields, and submit those to your form processor on step 3.

EDIT:

In other words, have your Confirm process post your hidden fields to another processor that creates your email content from the POST, and send TO the business, and yourself as a CC or BCC header.

```
<input name="AID" type="hidden" id="AID" value="<?php echo $_POST['AID']; ?>" size="32" />
```

Comment: uh, huh...I will try this. How do you store data into a hidden field?

Comment: Although this is possible, it is a bit of a hack, rather than a solution. Using sessions will not only get IdeaPimp learning, but using a more appropriate method.

Comment: <input name="AID" type="hidden" id="AID" value="<?php echo $_POST['AID']; ?>" size="32" />

Comment: @shane why are session variables more of a solution, and this method considered a hack?

Comment: Firstly, by hack, I mean it is a bit of a 'quick fix' kind of method, just to clear that up. And I call it so, because at any point, the page may be edited, changing the user's data, with or without their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can easily access the data via $_POST array, to send all this information to the respective recipients use the `mail()` function of php to create an email and send it over to whoever you want.

Comment: absolutely! all the data is there! its upto you to do what you want as long as the script is alive with the $_POST array! You can mail the data, store the data in a file etc etc